# .Net core and Sqlite deployment to azure failing

Tags: sqlite, azure, .net-core

I'm having difficulty deploying a .net core app using sqlite to azure. The error message I'm getting in my logs is:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryCompilationContextFactory[1]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
      Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: AspNetUserLogins'.
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Interop.MarshalEx.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, Sqlite3Handle db)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>d__53.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

This leads me to believe that my migrations aren't being applied correctly.

---

In my startup class I have the following:

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionName")));
```

and a connection string of :

```
"ConnectionName": "Filename=./MyApp.sqlite"
```

---

This works perfectly locally, but when I deploy to azure I get the given error. Any ideas what's gone wrong and what steps I can take to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a workaround.

I haven't worked out a way to apply migrations to sqlite as part of my deployment, everything I've tried on that front has caused errors. For the time being I found that finding the location of the .sqlite file in kudu, and then replacing it with my local .sqlite file is an acceptable workaround.